# How to make not to adjust web size with finger using webview app with Expo

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I am using webview at React native with Expo.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return <WebView source={{ uri: 'http://192.0.0.1:8080' }} />;
}
```

This is my webiew code.
 But I want to fix the webview without resizing with finger. How can I set this option? thank you so much.

Comment: Do u mean the pinch to zoom-in/out?

Comment: Yes. I want to fix window size not for pinching zoom-in out

Comment: you need to enable javascriptenable property true and need to add script in injectedjavascript property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below example and let me know if you can do it or not.

```
const INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT = `const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width='100%', initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `

   <WebView 
      ref={(reff) => {
              this.webView = reff;
           }}
            bounces={false}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
            startInLoadingState
            javaScriptEnabled ={true}

        />
```